# Idempotents in tensor product with a f.g. local Artin algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, idempotents

Let $k$ be a field.

Let $A$ and $B$ be $k$-algebras (commutative , with unit).

Assume that $A$ is finitely generated, local and Artinian.

Assume that the set of idempotents in $B$ is finite. (I stress that $B$ need not be finitely generated.)

Is the set of idempotents in ${A \otimes_k B}$ also finite?

(It is enough to assume that the only idempotents in $B$ are $0$ and $1$, but even in this case, maybe some unexpected idempotents appear in ${A \otimes_k B}$...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=\dim_k A$. First, I claim that if $B$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra and $\operatorname{Spec} B$ is connected then $\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes B$ has at most $n$ connected components.  To prove this, note that each connected component of $\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes B$ is of the form $\operatorname{Spec} C$ where $C$ is a finitely generated projective $B$-module (being a direct summand of $A\otimes B$).  In particular, $C$ is locally free as a $B$-module, and its local rank must be constant since $\operatorname{Spec} B$ is connected.  Since $C$ is nonzero, its local rank at each point is at least $1$.  Therefore if $\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes B$ has $m$ connected components, then the local rank of $A\otimes B$ as a $B$-module at each point is at least $m$.  But that local rank is equal to $n$, and thus $m\leq n$.

Now suppose $B$ is a $k$-algebra (not necessarily finitely generated) with no nontrivial idempotents, but $A\otimes B$ has infinitely many idempotents.  Then we can find a finitely generated subalgebra $B_0\subseteq B$ such that $A\otimes B_0$ contains more than $2^n$ idempotents.  This then implies $\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes B_0$ has more than $n$ connected components, contradicting the result above.  Thus $A\otimes B$ cannot have infinitely many idempotents (indeed, it cannot have more than $2^n$ idempotents).

(In fact, the reduction to the case where $B$ is finitely generated is unnecessary.  The only place this assumption is used in the first paragraph above is to conclude that the connected components of $\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes B$ are clopen (since there are only finitely many of them since $A\otimes B$ is Noetherian).  Without the assumption, the argument still shows that $\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes B$ cannot be decomposed as a disjoint union of more than $n$ nonempty clopen subsets, and this is enough to conclude that it has at most $n$ connected components.)

Comment: nice answer! But I need some time to process it (e.g. I do not know what local rank is.) Concerning the second paragraph: I understand that B is the colimit of its f.g. subalgebras, but why does the tensor with $A$ preserve that colimit?

Comment: Concretely, any element of $A\otimes B$ is a finite sum of elements $a_i\otimes b_i$, so every element (or finite set of elements) of $A\otimes B$ comes from $A\otimes B_0$ for some finitely generated $B_0$ (just take the subalgebra generated by the $b_i$).  Similarly, any relation between elements of $A\otimes B$ is witnessed by finitely many elements of $A$ and $B$ (consider the presentation of $A\otimes B$ as a certain quotient of the free module on $A\times B$), and in particular you need only finitely many elements of $B$ to witness that a given element is idempotent.

Comment: thanks. I pressed an arrow up and I'll mark the answer as "replied" as soon as I fully understand the details.

Comment: wait: Why is $C$ f.g. projective? I see that it is a retract of ${A \otimes B}$ but ${A \otimes B}$ need not be free as a $B$-module, as far as I can see.

Comment: As a $k$-module, $A$ is just $k^n$, so $A\otimes_k B$ is $B^n$ as a $B$-module.

Comment: you are right, of course. Also, I do not want to bother over each detail. Can you recommend a text book where I can learn the ingredients in the proof? E.g., the fact that connected spectrum implies constant local rank does not appear in my edition of Atiyah MacDonald...

Comment: This is just the fact that a locally constant function on a connected space is constant.  For each $i$, the subset of $\operatorname{Spec} B$ where $A\otimes B$ locally has rank $i$ is open, and thus clopen since these sets partition $\operatorname{Spec} B$.  So only one of them can be nonempty by connectedness.

Comment: I am getting there. I appreciate your patience @eric-wofsey. Because  ${A \otimes B}$ is free as a $B$-module it induces a locally constant rank function ${\mathrm{Spec} B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}}$ which, in fact, is constant because $B$ is connected.  Now, last bit: why constancy of this function imply that ${A \otimes B}$ has a finite number of idempotents? (It seems I am missing a basic fact about the relation between local ranks of ${A\otimes B}$ and its idempotents.)

Comment: This shows that $A\otimes B$ cannot be written as a direct sum of more than $n$ nonzero $B$-modules, since each direct summand would have local rank at least $1$ at every point and all of these local ranks must add up to $n$ since $A\otimes B$ is free of rank $n$.  If $A\otimes B$ had infinitely many idempotents, then it would contain arbitrarily large finite families of orthogonal idempotents, which would decompose it as a direct sum of arbitrarily large finite numbers of submodules.

Comment: Very nice @eric-wofsey. By the way, the assumption that $A$ is local does not seem to play any role.

Comment: That's correct, $A$ does not need to be local.

Comment: would it be possible to remove all the restrictions on $A$? That is, for a field $k$, and $A$, $B$  two $k$-algebras whose sets of idempotents are finite: Is the set of idempotents of ${A \otimes_k B}$ finite? (One could even ask the question for  an arbitrary ring $k$, but even the case over the complexes or the reals seems interesting. I guess there is a standard counter-example, but I could not find it.)

Comment: No.  For instance, $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C}$ has infinitely many idempotents.  It is true if $k$ is algebraically closed (you can reduce to the case where $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated and have no nontrivial idempotents, and then this is just the basic theorem in algebraic geometry that the product of two connected varieties over an algebraically closed field is connected).